# Using query to retrieve records which their createdate is a special date?

Tags: datetime

I have a table that has four columns.
One of them is named "CreateDate" and it's datatype is "DateTime".

Now, what would be a true T-SQL which retrieves records that their CreateDate is for example

"2010-02-10"  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to select all records with CreateDate on a specific date you could use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,CreateDate), 0) = '2010-02-10'
```

or

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME

SELECT @Date = '01 Feb 2010'

SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   CreateDate >= @Date
AND     CreateDate < @Date + 1
```

**EDIT**

If you wish to change the display format of the date, from [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

You could try

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(
        CreateDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable SELECT '01 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @YourTable SELECT GETDATE()


SELECT  *,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate, 120) DateValue
FROM @YourTable
```

Comment: I run this query based on yours and got below result:

Select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,CreateDate), 0) As 'DateOnly'

'2010-02-17 00:00:00.000'

As you can see, there is still time beside it.

Comment: Do you wish to display the CreateDate as *2010-02-10* or only select records that were created on that date? This is something slightly different.

Comment: Well, the first one (only date: yyyy-mm-dd)